# How do you declare a stack of type struct? in c++

Tags: c++, struct, stack

In the code below, how do you properly declare a stack of type struct and push strings onto the stack so that they are saved in the struct? How do you specify where you want to push the variable into a certain variable of the struct? The line that is causing an error is commented. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

struct purchasedItem
{
    string Name;
    float Cost;
};

int main()
{
    stack<purchasedItem> shoppingBasket;
    string word=" ";
    cout << "Enter some items:" << endl;
    while(word!="quit")
    {
        cin >> word;
        shoppingBasket.push(word); // this line causes an error
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a stack of `purchasedItem`s, but you are trying to put a `string` into it, which doesn't compile. You should instead make a `purchasedItem`, set its `Name` to the `word` and maybe initialize the `Cost` and `.push` that.

Comment: You create an instance of that type of containing your word and cost. Tehn you push that instance to the stack.

Comment: Off topic:  Because of the placement of the test, you will add the word quit to the stack (if that was possible) `while(cin >> word && word!="quit")` will read in a word, make sure it really was read and the stream didn't end or something, and then test that the word read isn't "quit".

Comment: Thank you! It works

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using std::stack for such operations: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: That's literally already being used in the code.